# Xiaomi Portrait Mode: Where is the original data stored (before depth-of-field effect)?

Tags: camera, xiaomi, photos, gallery

My Xiaomi 10T Pro has a "Portrait Mode" which blurs the background. When opening such a photo in the Gallery, the phone offers the option to adjust depth-of-field.

By default, a medium amount of depth-of-field is used. If I transfer that JPG to my computer, the background is slightly blurred.

When I open the picture in the phones Gallery app, it allows me to adjust depth-of-field and make the background more crisp. That must mean the phone stores the original image data somewhere. Otherwise, it wouldn't be able to un-blur the JPG file.

Where is that original image data stored?